# how to understanding A∩B in the multiplication formula of Probability

Tags: probability

I know P(A∩B)=P(A)P(B|A), how to understaing A∩B?

if A and B is independent, A∩B should be empty, so P(A∩B) will be zero.

I'm confused.

Comment: Do not confuse the phrase **Independent Events** with the phrase **Mutually Exclusive Events**.  Independent events are those for which $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.  Mutually exclusive events are those for which $A\cap B=\emptyset$

Answer (score 1):

$P(A \cap B) = P(A) \times P(B|A)$ or the probability that both $A$ and $B$ happen.

If $A$ and $B$ are **independent**, $P(A) = P(A|B)$ and $P(B) = P(B|A)$ - so neither has any impact on the other's probability. It follows that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \times P(B)$.

If $A$ and $B$ are **mutually exclusive**, $P(A|B) = 0 = P(B|A)$. This means that both events cannot happen: $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \times P(B|A) = P(A) \times 0 = 0$.

It is important to not confuse independence and mutual exclusiveness - they are fundamentally different concepts.